# TextField keyboard is lost when clearing text from within DataChangedListener

Tags: codenameone

I have a TextField on which I listen key presses

```
TextField msgField = new TextField();
msgField.setSingleLineTextArea(false);
msgField.addDataChangedListener((i1, i2) -> { ... });
```

I want to `clear()` the field's text when a certain key is pressed (enter key)

```
msgField.addDataChangedListener((i1, i2) -> { 
        if(!msgField.getText().isEmpty())
        {
            String lastChar = msgField.getText().substring(msgField.getText().length()-1);
            if(lastChar.equals("\n"))
            {
                msgField.clear();
            }
        }
});
```

When enter is pressed, the keyboard is closed on this field, which I am trying to prevent. How can I prevent this? `setText("")` (instead of `clear()`) produces a random number of further calls to `DataChanged` which messes things up (I tried wrapping with sync and control vars, no success there either). I have tested this on Android

Answer (score 1):

`DataChangedListener` is verbose so you shouldn't rely on it's low level behavior too much. In other words I'm not sure why `clear()` doesn't send events but it's possible it should... You need to guard against that in your `DataChangedListener` .

If you want to re-open the virtual keyboard just use `startEditingAsync` on the text field which will re-launch the text field. Notice that `clear` explicitly stops editing as invoking `setText` while editing can produce an inconsistent result as the user might be typing something on the native UI thread and you're trying to override him from the EDT. Stopping to make a change is essential to synchronize the native/lightweight components.

Comment: Unfortunately calling `startEditingAsync ` after `clear` from within `DataChaged` doesn't bring back the keyboard. I'd really appreciate any guidance on this, I need this to work. Thanks

Comment: Nevermind I achieved my goal (which was to mimic whatsapp's `TextField` growth) by calling `revalidate()` in every DataChanged. A bit expensive but works